# Competible : There's no word of concatenation of Compete(VB) + -able(suffix)?

Tags: word-usage

While having a conversation with my friend, it sounded as if she said *competible:*

> LG electronics is not competible to Daikin because of its gap of market shares between them ...

I actually understood what she said, but while hearing it, this also sounded to be confusable with *compatible.*
So, I looked into the Wiktionary, but there’s no word like *competible.*

Is this correct or is there a conventional use of this word?

Comment: What's your question here? Is it "Does *compatible* exist as a word?"? Clearly not, you've demonstrated that yourself with your research. Is it "Is there a word which means *able to compete*?"? If so, modify your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[**Competible**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/competible)* is actually a real (but obsolete) word, but it wasn't used to mean "able to compete". It meant either "appropriate" or "competent". The meaning of the English verb *compete* has shifted from its Latin origins.

The word ***[competitive](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/competitive)*** (*with*) might be closer to what you want. People sometimes say things like "X is not competitive with Y". Examples:

- "[Wind Power not Competitive with Conventional Sources](http://www.berlindailysun.com/opinion/columns/47234-wind-power-not-competitive-with-conventional-sources)" (*The Berlin Daily Sun*)
- > Confidential bid data provided by the utilities commission show that solar power generally was not competitive with other renewable sources.

  *[Solar Energy: As the Cost of This Resource Becomes More Competitive with Other Renewable Resources, Applications to Construct New Solar Power Plants Should Increase](https://books.google.com/books?id=cV580QnPhtYC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22not%20competitive%20with%22&source=bl&ots=zlOng4y_hB&sig=sV54Swc7DfbpamIcALXllSEkuPI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM5Jng8ZXWAhVI4oMKHa6VBTYQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=%22not%20competitive%20with%22&f=false),* California State Auditor, January 2008 Report

So it seems possible that someone might say

- "LG electronics is not competitive with Daikin because of the* gap in market shares between them."

However, in this context,  I think it might sound more natural to use the multi-word phrase "able to compete with". I'm not sure why, but "competitive with" just sounds a bit jargony to me. Opinions may vary on this.

- "LG electronics is not able to compete with Daikin because of the* gap in market shares between them."

### Tendencies in the formation of new words with *-able*

Verbs that take a direct object are called "transitive". When the suffix *-able* is used to form new words, it is typically added to some transitive verb "X" to create an adjective with the meaning "capable of being X'ed" or "worthy of being X'ed". Examples: *drinkable* ("capable of being drunk"), *lov(e)able* ("capable/worthy of being loved").

The word *compete* is not transitive: you can't say that something like "capable/worthy of being competed". So using "competible" or "compet(e)able" in the sense "capable of competing" would be a bit atypical.

There are a few *-able* words that have this kind of atypical meaning, like *perishable,* but it is not the norm (and in fact, it used to be possible to use the word *perish* as a transitive verb, hence the expression "perish the thought!").

See this ELL post for more details: [Is putting -able to any verb allowed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15203/is-putting-able-to-any-verb-allowed)

---

*side note: "because of its gap of market shares between them" is not worded correctly, so I corrected it to "because of the gap in market shares between them". This is incidental to the question.

Comment: As a activr user of American English I can't help myself thinking about efficiency. As you just clearly mentioned, able to compete - thie able and verb combination is widely accepted as form ot verb with suffixed -able. But why do yoi think competible not become popular but being obsolete doyou think?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your so valuable knowledge. Thanks to you now I could put a more classifier to research on working of -able with relation to verb.

Comment: "Competitive with" is quite common in American business. So it is standard there. Whether it is jargon depends on how standard it is among the general population.

Answer (score 1):

It is not even clear what was intended (although the overall context may have made it clear).

It would make perfect sense to interpret the given sentence as intending "not competitive with" as suggested by sumelic. And that seems to be the most probable intention. But the intended meaning may also have been "not comparable to." And possibly the speaker was considering both concepts and scrambled the phrases denoting them into one scrambled phrase.